# How to produce APA style statistical output in Sweave?

Tags: r, sweave

I am trying to find a way to integrate statistical output from the [apa](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apa/apa.pdf) R package in Sweave.

I need to use the [ez](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/ez.pdf) package for my statistical analysis (as I need type 3 sum of squares). This works perfectly with Rmarkdown, but I am having problems with the format of the output in Sweave.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\section*{Results}
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
library(knitr)
library(ez)
library(apa)

subject<- c(1:40)
reward<- rep(c("p", "s", "p", "s", "s", "p", "s", "p", "s", "p"), 4)
class<- rep(c("ST", "GT", "ST", "GT", "GT", "ST", "GT", "ST", "GT", "ST"), 4)
value<- runif(40, min=0, max=5)
df<- data.frame(subject, reward, class, value)
df$subject<- as.factor(df$subject)

analysis<- ezANOVA(data= df, dv=.(value), wid= .(subject),between = .(class), detailed= TRUE, type= 3)
apa.format<- apa(analysis, format= "text")
@

The results, \Sexpr{(apa.format[2,2])}, indicate...

\end{document}
```

The result it should produce is:
*F*(1, 38) = 0.93, *p* = .341, ηp² = .02
I have tried to change the format from the `apa` function, and every output produces a different issue:
* latex: produces textit (and it does not make the 'F' italic or the 'p')
* markdown: makes the the '*' instead of producing italic.
* text: does not produce the italic or the partial eta squared symbol.
This can be achieved easily in Rmarkdown, however I had many other issues. 
Suggestions? This may include: different package for APA reporting in Sweave, a different way to integrate Latex and Rcode (and use packages) or a fix to the previous output.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\Sexpr` macro appears to "eat" the backslashes that `apa()` puts into the output, so you need to double them.  So choose `"latex"` format, and then double the backslashes:

```
apa.format <- apa(analysis, format= "latex")
apa.format <- gsub("\\", "\\\\", as.matrix(apa.format), fixed = TRUE)
```

This fixes all entries of `apa.format` so they are compatible with `\Sexpr`.  The `as.matrix` is necessary, because `apa.format` is a tibble, and it wouldn't work nicely with `gsub()`.  (I imagine you could do the same using `mutate` or something like that, if you know what you're doing with tibbles.  I don't.)

Output is

[image: screenshot]